# Error installing websockets package for Haskell in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, cabal-install

I'm trying to install a package to the Haskell Platform in Cygwin.  It requires the websockets package, for which the most recent version is 0.9.0.1.

My command looks like:

```
cabal install websockets
```

And I get the following error message during the build (it downloads fine):

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring websockets-0.9.0.1...
Building websockets-0.9.0.1...
Failed to install websockets-0.9.0.1
Last 10 lines of the build log ( C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\websockets-0.9.0.1.log ):
Building websockets-0.9.0.1...
Preprocessing library websockets-0.9.0.1...
[ 1 of 11] Compiling Network.WebSockets.Hybi13.Mask ( src\Network\WebSockets\Hybi13\Mask.hs, dist\build\Network\WebSockets\Hybi13\Mask.o )
[ 2 of 11] Compiling Network.WebSockets.Http ( src\Network\WebSockets\Http.hs, dist\build\Network\WebSockets\Http.o )
[ 3 of 11] Compiling Network.WebSockets.Types ( src\Network\WebSockets\Types.hs, dist\build\Network\WebSockets\Types.o )
[ 4 of 11] Compiling Network.WebSockets.Stream ( src\Network\WebSockets\Stream.hs, dist\build\Network\WebSockets\Stream.o )

src\Network\WebSockets\Stream.hs:24:57:
    Module `Network.Socket.ByteString.Lazy' does not export `sendAll'
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
websockets-0.9.0.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I have a default install of Cygwin x64 and Haskell Platform x64 on Windows 7 Pro x64.  Is there a workaround to this?  Or am I missing some configuration?

I have the same `cabal` update issue mentioned at http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2010-June/004357.html, where my updated cabal version is not being used (I keep getting notified about a newer version), but the install command keeps saying the new version installed fine.  I'm not sure if that has something to do with this...

Answer (score 1):

I did not find an actual answer for why the most current version of websockets won't build, but what fixed my issue is installing an older version of websockets.

```
cabal install websockets-0.8.6.2
```